# Show youtube video controls when video ended

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a youtube video that starts running without controls as I specified when creating the object.

I want to show the controls when the video ended, how to do that?
Here is my code:

```
 var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'cZ5zFdViWlE',
          playerVars : {
            'controls' :0
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {   

          //code to show controls should be here


        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not really how the player API works; when you set controls to 0 in creating the embed, you aren't just hiding the controlbar but creating the iframe without one. And there is not an exposed method to then create a controlbar later.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to do it another way then I will be able to achieve what I want?

Comment: No ... what I meant was that the controls parameter isn't a show/hide thing, but you are creating the player without them, so there is no way to then show them later.

Comment: Aha, you are right thanks.. I solved my problem by creating one page contains the video without controls, and when the video ends, a button appears to redirect the user to another page contains the video with controls